# Assigning value inside while condition

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign the return value of `read` to a variable and at the same time check a condition on that value inside the while condition.

```
while(reader=(read(fd, temp, BUFFER_SIZE)) >= BUFFER_SIZE)
```

But instead of assigning the right value, the value of the condition is assigned (0 or 1).
How can I solve this? I need to assign it to a variable because i'll use it afterwards, and I cannot declare it inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment must be parenthesized, not just the function call:

```
while ((reader = read(fd, temp, BUFFER_SIZE)) >= BUFFER_SIZE) ...
```

Note however that the number of bytes read cannot be larger than the number requested and depending on the type and signedness of `reader`, the comparison will use signed or unsigned arithmetics, making a return value of `-1` greater than `BUFFER_SIZE`. To avoid this, `reader` must be defined as `ssize_t` or some other signed type.

To further complicate things, `BUFFER_SIZE` could be defined as an unsigned quantity, such as `#define BUFFER_SIZE  4096U` or `#define BUFFER_SIZE  sizeof(temp)`, which will also force unsigned arithmetics even if `reader` has a signed type...

Here is a safer approach:

```
    unsigned char temp[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t nread;

    while ((nread = read(fd, temp, sizeof temp)) > 0) {
        // handle nread bytes...
    }
    if (nread < 0) {
        // handle read error
    } else {
        // reached end of file successfully
    }
```

The above loop will not handle signals that may cause `read` to return `-1`.
you can add a special test for this:

```
    unsigned char temp[BUFFER_SIZE];
    ssize_t nread;

    for (;;) {
        nread = read(fd, temp, sizeof temp);
        if (nread < 0) {
            if (errno == EINTR) {
                // read attempt was interrupted by signal, restart
                continue;
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "read error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
        if (nread == 0) {
            // normal end of file
            break;
        }
        // handle nread bytes...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`>=` has higher precedence than `=`. The way you wrote your code is equivalent to doing the following:

1. `TEMP = read(fd, temp, BUFFER_SIZE);`
2. `reader = (TEMP) >= BUFFER_SIZE;`

Which due to the precedence rules, stores a boolean value in `reader`.

What you wanted was to store `TEMP` into `reader` and compare `reader` with `BUFFER_SIZE`, then you need to put some parenthesis so the assignment gets done before the comparison, which would change `2.` to: `(reader = TEMP) >= BUFFER_SIZE;`

So your code should be:

```
while((reader= read(fd, temp, BUFFER_SIZE)) >= BUFFER_SIZE)
```